# npm install fails with 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir' error

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-package

`
PS F:\our company\Triyotech India\client> npm i
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path \?
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '\?'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: D:\npm-cache_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal`

how to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

run `New-Item -Path "$PWD\.npm-cache" -ItemType Directory -Force`

then run

```
 npm config set cache "$PWD\.npm-cache"
```

then run `npm install`

it work in my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).